# App doesn't want to launch after creating a splash screen

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, splash-screen

I am working on an Android app source code that I downloaded from Github. The code has only one activity which is the main activity. So I decided to create another activity to display a splash screen every time the user runs the application but after creating the splash screen the app doesn't run anymore.

A snippet of the **Splash Activity class**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Thread myThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
    //.....
}
```

And this is the **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.csab.soundboard">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:parentActivityName=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.csab.soundboard.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is what I get when I run the app on a virtual device:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: add the logcat and view message Android Monitor Overview

Answer (score 0):

You need a handler for `startActivity(intent);`

```
    //........
    //Handles the thread result of the Backup being executed.
    final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    };

    Thread myThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(2000);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   };
   myThread.start();
   //......
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler instead of Thread.

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `<intent filter><intent filter/>` from your MainActivity class in manifest. That have to work